# заполнить пробелом для корректного отображения

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

есть массив с циклом и логикой. Нужно добавить пробелы вначале чтобы было видно полностью елку, а не только одну сторону
Пример:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

```js
    let a = 1, b = 3, c = 21;
const out = []
while (a < c) {
  out.push(new Array(b)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, length) => {
        const ol = length * 2 + (a - 1) + 1
        return " ".repeat(Math.max(0, c - Math.ceil((ol / 2 ) + 2))) + "*".repeat(ol)
    })
    .join("\n"));
  a+= 2;
  b++;
}

console.log("\n" + out.join('\n') + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let a = 1, b = 3;
while (a < 11) {
  console.log(new Array(b).fill(0).map((_, length) => " ".repeat(40-length*2-b)+"* ".repeat(2*length + a)).join("\n"));
  a++;
  b++;
}
```

Comment: можно сделать поровнее?

Comment: исправил свой вопрос

Comment: в вашем изначальном алгоритме на чётных секциях ёлки было четное количество звёзд на линии в каждом ярусе. из-за этого нарушалась симетрия с секциями, где звезд на каждой линии нечетное количество. Сперва я писал код с мобильного и мне было сложно посмотреть визуальное подтверждение. Позже мне пришлось добавить пробелы между звездами, что бы не менять их количество из вашего решения, но сместить на один символ влево каждую новую секцию.

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант решения

```js
let a = 1, b = 3, c = 21;
const out = []
while (a < c) {
  out.push(new Array(b)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, length) => {
        const ol = length * 2 + (a - 1) + 1
        return " ".repeat((c - 1) - Math.ceil(ol / 2) + 2)  + "*".repeat(ol)
    })
    .join("\n"));
  a+=2;
  b++;
}

console.log("\n" + out.join('\n') + "\n")
```